# Show that if a subset of a metric space is sequentially closed then it is closed

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, metric-spaces

I would like to know if my proof is correct for the following :

> Let $(E,d)$ be a metric space and $C\subset E$. If $C$ is sequentially closed then it is closed

My attempt is : Let $C$ be sequentially closed :

$$
\forall x\in C^{\mathbb{N}} : lim_{n\to\infty}x_n = l \implies l\in C
$$

Now consider $E\setminus C$, we have : $\forall x\in E\setminus C, d(x,l)>0$ since $l\notin E\setminus C$. Let $x\in E\setminus C$ and consider $\varepsilon = d(x,l)$, we have that $y\in B_{\varepsilon}(x)\implies y\in E\setminus C$.  Indeed

$$
y\in B_{\varepsilon}(x)\implies d(x,y)<d(x,l)\leq d(x,y) + d(y,l)\implies 0<d(y,l)\implies y\in E\setminus C
$$

Since this is true for all $x\in E\setminus C$, this shows that $E\setminus C$ is open and thus $C$ is closed. Is this seems correct to you ? Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me restate your proof.

1. Let $x\in E\setminus C$ be arbitrary.
2. Define $\epsilon=d(x,l)$.
3. $d(x,y)<d(x,l)\le d(x,y)+d(y,l)$.
4. $0<d(y,l)$.
5. $y\in E\setminus C$.

Step $(5)$ is just wrong; you have asserted it but there is no way to deduce it. The property $d(y,l)>0$ (i.e., $y\neq l$) would not imply that $y\in E\setminus C$ if $C$ has more than one element (say $C$ contains $\ell$ and some other point $p$. Then with $y=p$, $d(y,l)>0$ but it is *false* that $y\in E\setminus C$).

More pressingly, step $(2)$ is "wrong" in the sense that $\ell$ is *undefined*. You cannot use an undefined object in a proof. If you want to create some suitable $\ell$, you need to choose a suitable sequence.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, clearly step 5 is false yes, I should have been more careful. For step $2$, I am not sure to fully understand, if the set is nonempty it is natural to consider a sequence $x_n$ without explicitly define this sequence no ? It is something I used to do a lot of time (i.e "let $x_n$ be a convergent sequence in \mathbb{R}^{n}$..." to prove Heine-Borel theorem for example) so am I missing something ? Thank you !

Comment: @coboy Without defining $\ell$, $\ell$ could be literally any element of $C$. Then $\epsilon$ is not defined, so $B_\epsilon$ is not defined, so ... there is not really any proof. If you had just said, "let $\ell$ be some element of $C$" that's fine. But using $\ell$ without specifying to the reader - or to yourself - what it actually is, is dangerous, and on a pedantic level it's just wrong (proofs cannot rest on undefined objects)

Comment: But this is clear by the fact that $C$ is sequentially closed that $l$ is in $C$ since I defined $x_n$ as a sequence of $C$ that converges to $l$ no ? Agree with the rest of your comment on the fact that not specifying where objects are living is dangerous ! Thank you.

Comment: @coboy But what is $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$? You didn't define *that* either. On a different note, I strongly recommend you think about making a suitable and *specific* choice of sequence and of $\ell$. "The" proof that sequentially closed sets are closed in a metric space relies on making specific definitions of $\ell$; if you don't bother to define $\ell$, you are probably not thinking along the right lines. I haven't written a correct proof here because it's been answered on the site many times and is readily found online

Comment: $x\in C^{\mathbb{N}}$ is the notation to represent an element of the set $C^{\mathbb{N}}$ of functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $C$ and $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is the sequence associated to this element $x$. So $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is just a sequence in $C$. I was lazy on the writing, but I thought this was not unusual, sorry ! Thank you for these clarifications, I will look on the internet !

Comment: @coboy No, I understood the notation $x\in C^{\Bbb N}$. *But you didn't define a sequence $x$!* You defined an element $x\in E\setminus C$. You did not define an associated sequence $x:\Bbb N\to C$

Comment: The letter $x$ was used twice in my (not correct) proof, I'm talking about the first use which is related to the sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ which was the subject of your previous question. I wasn't talking about the second use $x\in E\setminus C$ which seems clear enough to me. Perhaps I should have changed the letter, sorry.

Comment: @coboy Right. But you haven't defined a sequence $x$, my point still stands. It's a common mistake for students to treat a "$\forall x...$" symbol as a definition of $x$, but this is not so. When you refer to $x_n$, I ask you, what are the elements? What is $x_1$? What is $x_2$? Etc. none of this has been defined

Comment: I see, the use of the quantifier is not appropriate in this situation, I have tried to fix that in the post. About $x_1$, $x_2$, ... they are just elements of $C$ ?

Comment: @coboy *which elements*? And no, the use of the quantifier $\forall$ *was* appropriate (as a definition of sequentially closed). I'm just saying, your treatment of $(x_n)$ as something that's already been defined was not appropriate.

Comment: Now, you've changed the wording of the post so that some of my previous comments are moot. Now $\ell,(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ are defined (as some arbitrary sequences)

Comment: Okay I see. You want that I defined explicitly $(x_n)$, but when you want to prove a property related to convergent sequences, this need to hold for any convergent sequence in the space we are considering, so I don't see how it makes sense to define explicitly a sequence since this sequence would not be arbitrary.

Comment: Yes as I said in my previous comment I have tried to fix this issue. But I put back the mistake so that our conversation keeps its meaning, thank you.

Comment: @coboy "When you want to prove a property ..." - we weren't trying to prove that $C$ is sequentially closed, though, we were already told this. If you had just said (which you did in a recent edit) "let $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ be some convergent sequence of elements of $C$" then that would be completely fine.

Comment: Yes, you are right ! To use* sorry, not to prove. But I see your point now and it is fair. Thank you for taking the time to explain me this !

Comment: @coboy no worries!